# How to determine type of Html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table with 3 columns.

1. is hidden and is containing "id" of selected row
2. is containing "product" name
3. is containing an yes/no  denoting product is present or not

On Row click push the details to an array as

```
$("#Product_grid_wrapper table tr").click(function () {

        //empty the array
        selectedProduct = [];

        $('#Product_grid_wrapper table tr').removeClass("row_selected");

        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            selectedProduct.push($(this).text());
        });

        $(this).addClass("row_selected");
    });
```

But I was asked to change the "yes/no" with an image.I did it perfectly. Now the third column is containing Image tag , with image setting at runtime using aspx

but the code

```
 selectedProduct.push($(this).text());
```

will fail for 3rd column as it is containing the image.How to handle this case?

I am able to give a class="yes/no" to Image tag from Server.But how can I read this value as per above code.can I find the type of content of table col and use appropriate function

```
 $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            //if(type of content of td is image tag)   
            {
               selectedProduct.push($(this).html());
               //will extract "class    " of image tag to get "yes/no" value
            }  
            else{
                 selectedProduct.push($(this).text());
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added a class yes/no to the image, you could try this:

```
if($(this).find('img').length == 1) {
    selectedProduct.push($(this).find('img').attr('class'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `html()`instead of `text()`

```
selectedProduct.push($(this).html());
```

Comment: but ir will give some weird values for image tag while array is printed in console.I tried it already

Answer (score 0):

Try using attributes in your elements instead of hiding columns and missusing css-classes if possible. Maybe like this:

```
<tr id="123">
    <td>_productName</td>
    <td>
        <img data-present="yes" src="..." />
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can then use:

```
selectedProduct.push({id : $(this).id, present : $(this).find('img').data('present')});
```